# RejectedExecutionException in ScheduledThreadPoolExcecutor

Tags: android, multithreading

I am getting following exception while staring a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. I use this to poll server every one minute.

```
01-11 18:45:50.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2427): Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: pool=0/2147483647, queue=0
```

My code

```
stpe.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {  
        public void run() {  

            //Start Polling:
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            System.out.println( sdf.format(cal.getTime()) );
            Log.d("Polling", sdf.format(cal.getTime()) + " Polling for devices");

            HttpUtil httpUtil = new HttpUtil(mContext);
            httpUtil.setJNAPCode(R.string.action_devices);
            httpUtil.executeJNAPAction(true);


        }  
    },0, 60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This is called when an activity is created. I am getting this exception every alternate time I start the activity i.e it works the next time it loads after crashing.

I shut it down using **stpe.shutdownNow()** before finishing the activity. But when next time this activity is created after loading the application I get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can't submit a new task once the executor is shutdown.You could store the future returned by the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method and cancel it before leaving the activity while keeping the executor running. Reschedule the task when the activity is resumed.

Or alternatively: shutdown the executor when leaving the activity and **create** a new one when the activity is resumed.

Comment: I am not creating a new task after shutting down the stpe. It is shutdown only while coming out the app. But when the next time the app loads and I try to submit I get this.

Comment: I am not an Android specialist but I think your app retains its state when you leave it and come back. So unless you create a new instance of the executor in onStart you will be using the previous instance that is shutdown.

Comment: So you would create the executor in onCreate, submit the task in onStart, cancel it in onStop and shutdown the executor in onDestroy I think.